# How to handle multiple relationships between two tables in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relationship

Dear Entity Framework Core Experts,

I've got two entities along the lines of...

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    
    public Clan? Clan { get; set; }

    public int? ClanId { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Clan
{
    public int ClanId { get; set; }

    public Account Leader { get; set; }

    public int LeaderId { get; set; }

    public IList<Account>? Officers { get; set; }

    public IList<Account>? Members { get; set; }
}
```

...where the following conditions apply:

- an account may or may not have a clan
- a clan always has one leader
- a clan may or may not have officers
- a clan may or may not have members

Given the above configuration, I can't, for the life of me, figure out what fluent mappings I need to write to make it work. Any guidance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked at solutions for other similar questions, but none of them really apply to my case, as far as I could tell, because the `Leader` cannot be optional and removing conventions doesn't feel like a *safe* approach.

Many Thanks

Comment: I think I'd have just made it 1:M on Clan:Account and had a type on the account, or maybe it's M.M and the decomposing table can have the type (leader; officer; member)

Comment: Thanks, @CaiusJard, that's actually exactly what I've ended up doing. I've added a `ClanTier` enum used for a new property on `Account` and then `Clan` has just one list of Members. It feels like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I managed to get Entity Framework Core to accept the migration by doing the following...</s>

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Clan>().Ignore(clan => clan.Leader);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Clan>().Ignore(clan => clan.Officers);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Clan>().Ignore(clan => clan.Members);
}
```

...however, I'm not entirely sure whether this is the best approach to the problem.

UPDATE: In hindsight, the initial entity design felt bad so I added a `ClanTier` enum which I now use for a new `ClanTier` property on `Account`, and now `Clan` has just one list of `Members`, so now it's a standard 1:M relationship. The two classes now look like the below:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    
    public Clan? Clan { get; set; }

    public int? ClanId { get; set; }

    public ClanTier ClanTier { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Clan
{
    public int ClanId { get; set; }

    public IList<Account>? Members { get; set; }
}
```